# Get current time in android or ios device

Tags: android, ios, datetime, saucelabs

I am running test in Local Android device. I have configured time interval. My timings are below

Local time:-

```
Friday 19:37  to Friday 21:38
```

Saucelabs time:-

```
Friday 6:07  to Friday 8:08
```

When I ran test. I am expecting local time to be present. But time are mismatching. How can I do comparison properly using driver instance irrespective of device / simulator time settings ?

Comment: show us your code please

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for Get current Date and time in IOS (Objective-C):

```
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *newDateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@"newDateString %@", newDateString);
[outputFormatter release];
```

And for Swift :

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in Swift 4:-

```
func getCurrentTime(){

    let strTime: String = "Device Time: " + String(describing: Date())

    print(strTime)
}
```